# É possível atribuir um valor para um input com display none?

Tags: javascript

Eu e meus amigos somos bem iniciantes no ramo da programação e estamos desenvolvendo um código para nos auxiliar nas tarefas da escola; mas chegamos a um ponto onde ficamos presos. **Quando dou o console.log do input enquanto o display está como none, ele imprime a tag como no HTML mesmo. Como posso atribuir um valor 0?**

HTML:

```
<div class="inputContainer">
    <h1>Marque o(s) tipo(s) de ar(es) condicionado(s) instalado(s) em sua casa:</h1>
                        
    <br>

    <div class="check">
         <input type="checkbox" id="checkJanela" onclick="checking()">
         <label for="checkJanela"></label> JANELA
    </div>
</div>

<div class="inputContainer" id="input1Janela">
    <h1>Quantos deles (JANELA) têm uma potência MENOR OU IGUAL a 9000 BTU/h?</h1>

    <input type="number" class="inputs" id="janelaMenor9k" placeholder="Número de ares condicionados JANELA com potência <= 9000 BTU/h">
</div>

<button type="submit" onclick="calc()">Calcular</button>
```

JS:

```
function checking() {
    let checkJanela = document.getElementById("checkJanela")
    if (checkJanela.checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("input1Janela").style.display = "block"
    } else {
        document.getElementById("input1Janela").style.display = "none"
    }
}

function calc() {
    var display1Janela = document.getElementById("input1Janela").style.display
    var janelaMenor9k = document.getElementById("janelaMenor9k")
    if (display1Janela == "none") {
        janelaMenor9k === 0
    } else if (display1Janela == "block") {
        janelaMenor9k = parseInt(document.getElementById("janelaMenor9k").value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

No seu primeiro IF, que você está verificando se o display é igual a none, ao invés de inserir um valor a variável janelaMenor9k você está comparando se ela é igual a 0. Lembre-se, para atribuir um valor você utiliza apenas um sinal de igual, para comparar você utiliza dois ou três sinais de igual.
Outra coisa, para você adicionar valor a um input do tipo number você terá que utilizar um método, tente da seguinte forma:

```
if (display1Janela == "none") {
    janelaMenor9k.value = 0;
}
```